# Как буквально перевести Class.prototype = Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

интересуют два меленьких вопроса, которые не хочется расписывать в двух разных вопросах!

```js
function Class(age){
  this.age=age
};

Class.prototype = Object.prototype; 

var best = new Class(25);

document.write((best.constructor===Class)+"<br>"); //false
document.write((best.constructor===Object)+"<br>"); //true
```

1. Как, абсолютно буквально прочитать строчку `Class.prototype = Object.prototype` ? 
   Объекту `Class.prototype` присваивается значением Объект `Object`, который является прототипом всех объектов? Или в данной операции присваивания `Class.prototype` не является ссылкой на объект, а лишь пустой ссылкой, которая не имеет никакого смысла в данной операции присваивания, до того момента, пока мы не присвоили ей ссылку на объект?
2. И второй вопрос, что есть `.constructor`?
    Если я в своем коде выполнил операцию присваивания `Class.prototype = Object.prototype`, и этот самый `.constructor` уже не указывает на казалось бы ТУ (Class) функцию, с помощью которой создался объект `best`?

Comment: Вы вот это читали? https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance

Comment: @Stranger in the Q , привет, спасибо что ответил! В принципи урок на ljs.ru мне понятен, и конструкцию `Rabit.prototype=Object.create(Animal.prototype)` реализующую наследование между "классами" я понял НО по видимому у меня пробел в знаниях, т.к. смысл `Class.prototype = Object.prototype` меня сбивает с толку (в плане необходимости, и НЕкостыльности), поэтому и задал вопрос, и в чем будет раздница между моей записью, и к примеру `Class.prototype=Object.create(Object.prototype)`?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, вай вай вай, моя невнимательность, мои извинения. `Class.prototype = Object.prototype` получается сделает так, что это будет один объект, и если у них есть методы с одинаковым названием к примеру, это присваивание приведёт к тому, что методы перезапишутся, извини за беспокойство! -_-